# `GNAT.SOCKETS.SOCKET_ERROR: [11]` Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: sockets, server, udp, ada, gnat

I'm using this `server` to receive several data packages from a `C++` `UDP Client`.
When i need a package i send a `Request` using a `Client UDP` to get the `C++` Client send the package. When i do this process several times, i miss some packages and receive this error:

`GNAT.SOCKETS.SOCKET_ERROR: [11] Resource temporarily unavailable`

I think may cause because the client send the package before the server is listening, but I'm not sure. Is there any way to solve it?? If that is the problem, is there any way to ensure that my server is prepared before the client send the `UDP` message?

```
procedure RECEIVE_DATA (
                            DEST_UDP_PORT        : In  Integer;
                            SRC_UDP_PORT         : In  Integer;
                            WAIT_TIME            : In  DURATION;
                            MESSAGE_ADDRESS      : Out System.Address;
                            WAIT_RESULT          : Out Integer;
                            MESSAGE_SIZE         : Out Integer
                           ) is


   Address  : Sock_Addr_Type;
   Socket   : Socket_Type;
   Channel  : Stream_Access;
   Receive_Timeout : constant Duration := WAIT_TIME;
   Offset : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Count;
   Data   : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Array (1 .. 10000);

begin
   Initialize (Process_Blocking_IO => False);
   WAIT_RESULT := 0;
   MESSAGE_SIZE := 0;
   -- Create Socket
   Create_Socket (Socket, Family_Inet, Socket_Datagram);
   Set_Socket_Option (Socket => Socket,
                      Option => (Gnat.Sockets.Receive_Timeout, Timeout => Receive_Timeout));

   --Bind Address
   Address.Addr := Inet_Addr(DEFINE_IP_ADDR.IP_BOARD_ADDRESS);
   Address.Port := Port_Type(DEST_UDP_PORT);
   Bind_Socket (Socket, Address);

   Channel := Stream (Socket, Address);
   -- Receive Socket
   Ada.Streams.Read (Channel.All, Data, Offset);  

   -- Close socket
   Free (Channel);
   Close_Socket (Socket);
   WAIT_RESULT := 1;
   MESSAGE_SIZE := Integer(Offset);
   MESSAGE_ADDRESS := Data'Address;
   Finalize;
exception when E : others =>
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        (Exception_Name (E) & ": " & Exception_Message (E));
      WAIT_RESULT := 0;
      Free (Channel);
      Close_Socket (Socket);
      Finalize;      
end RECEIVE_DATA ;
```

Comment: I don’t understand why you have a task at all; might as well inline the body in the procedure. All having a task can do is run the risk of missing the expected message. Does `Receive_Data` get called with different port numbers? because, if not, I’d set up the socket once and pass the socket to `Receive_Data`. `Integer’Size` is 32, perhaps you want to update `Message_Size` by `Offset` instead! (and `Offset` will be the number of 8-bit bytes, anyway, nothing to to with `Integer`).

Comment: Ok sorry, now it is updated. Yes, i use the function to get called with different port numbers.

Comment: Maybe you should prepare the socket to receive the message before you ask the client to send it? And, it is a **very very bad idea** to pass the address of an array declared on the stack of a procedure out to the caller of that procedure.

Comment: I have tried to prepare the socket before sending the request and the result is the same. This procedure is implemented into a loop with the procedure of the request of data and it works perfectly hundred of iterations, but after a while it fail. The client send the last package (i check it with wireshark) but the server does not read it.

Comment: You are getting this error (`EAGAIN`) because you’ve specified a timeout and the datagram hasn’t arrived within that timeout. UDP isn’t reliable, datagrams might get lost, but the most likely reason is that the client sent the reply before your server had completed setting up the socket to receive it.

Comment: The problem is that the client has already sent the package before the timeout. If i don't set the timeout, it waits forever. So the problem is the same, it is not receiving the message.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change

```
Address.Addr := Inaddr_Any;
```

This is the address you are receiving from: not your address.  Set your address when sending and any when receiving